# Homebrew Mariadb Mysql installation root access denied

Tags: mysql, macos, mariadb, homebrew

So I basically am installing mariadb with mysql on my mac using homebrew.
These are the steps I made:

- brew doctor -> worked
- brew update -> worked
- brew install mariadb -> worked
- mysql_install_db -> Failed

  > WARNING: The host 'Toms-MacBook-Pro.local' could not be looked up
  >   with /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.6_1/bin/resolveip. This probably
  >   means that your libc libraries are not 100 % compatible with this
  >   binary MariaDB version. The MariaDB daemon, mysqld, should work
  >   normally with the exception that host name resolving will not work.
  >   This means that you should use IP addresses instead of hostnames when
  >   specifying MariaDB privileges ! mysql.user table already exists!

Running `mysql_upgrade` afterwards gave me following error:

> Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql'
>   command line client ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

I can't enter mysql like this:

```
mysql -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

but like this:

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

The user table returns this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> USE mysql;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
MariaDB [mysql]> SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
+---------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| User          | Host                    | plugin                |
+---------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| root          | localhost               | mysql_native_password |
| toms          | localhost               | mysql_native_password |
|               | localhost               |                       |
|               | toms-macbook-pro.local |                       |
+---------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.004 sec)
```

Comment: You don't need to run manually `mysql_install_db`. Try to `brew remove mariadb ` and reinstall again.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni the point is that I had this error earlier and reinstalled it, but it did not solve it, mariadb run automatically `mysql_install_db` right? (or something similiar)

Comment: `mysql_install_db` is run by the Homebrew's Mariadb install script at `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/mariadb.rb` but it needs some specific parameters.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could try to update the root password and access it afterwards

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
```

Exit Mysql and try to login

```
mysql -uroot -p # then use root as a password
```

Comment: How would one update the root password without being able to login as root?  This is not a solution.   The solution is first do the one below about running it from CLI as sudo (unix sockets) then run this.

Answer (score 3):

MariaDB 10.4 enables [Unix socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/) authentication plugin for the local root by default. It means that on a freshly installed system you can connect to a running server without a password, as long as you are a local root (e.g. run under `sudo`) and using a socket rather than TCP.

Further, MariaDB 10.4 allows multiple authentication methods for accounts. It configures the local root to be able to use password authentication as well, but it initially invalidates the password (doesn't set an empty password as it used to). If you want to use the password authentication and connect as `mysql -uroot -p`, you need first connect as a root using Unix socket and run `SET PASSWORD=...`.

The advanced user configuration is now stored in `mysql.global_priv` table in JSON format. `mysql.user` has been kept for backward compatibility, but it has stopped being a table and has become a view. As a consequence of allowing multiple authentication methods, it doesn't always show user configuration accurately. Specifically, it doesn't show all authentication methods available for a user, you need to query `mysql.global_priv` for that. On a fresh installation, you'll see something like

```
+-----------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Host      | User   | Priv                                                                                                                                       |
+-----------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| localhost | root   | {"access":18446744073709551615,"plugin":"mysql_native_password","authentication_string":"invalid","auth_or":[{},{"plugin":"unix_socket"}]} |
...
```

You can find more information about 10.4 authentication changes [here](https://mariadb.org/authentication-in-mariadb-10-4/).

Comment: That's great but how is this a solution? This is just information.

Comment: Solution for what, exactly? If the author wants to connect as a `root` via UNIX socket (in other words, without a password), he already figured out how to do so and wrote about it, `sudo mysql`; I would assume the remaining question was *why*, and the above is the explanation. If the author wants to connect with password authentication, without having to `sudo`, the solution is to set the password first, as the 2nd paragraph of the above answer suggests.

Comment: Okay I've downvoted your answer, and upvoted the other answer. Thanks.

Comment: This answer is controversial but I have to upvote it. I came here, because I installed MariaDB on my local machine and couldn't connect. This answer explains why, just use `sudo` when doing something with the root user on your local machine.

Comment: This ultimately helped me, but the actual solution is:  Run cli using above / sudo, THEN change the password using the accepted answer (which is not a real solution either)

Answer (score 3):

## What is the issue?

- Install MariaDB using brew, `brew install mariadb@10.2`.
- Try to reset root password.

  - Method 1: `mysqld_safe` command

    - run command: `brew services stop mariadb@10.2`
    - run command: `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking`
    - on a new terminal tab,
      run command for MariaDB <= 10.4: `mysql_secure_installation`
      run command for MariaDB >= 10.4 `mariadb-secure-installation`
    - this will ask to enter root password
    - hit enter without entering any password (this step might never go away!)
    - if empty root password is granted in previous step 
      enter and re-enter new password in the next steps
    - this could show some errors `Password update failed!`
  - Method 2: `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password`

    - this will ask to enter password
    - hit enter without entering any password
    - this will show some errors!

**But preceding two methods did not work!**

- Follow the working method:

  - start the mariadb@10.2 service `brew services start mariadb@10.2`
  - run `mysql.servert start`
  - this will show an error with error log file location
  - typical mariadb error file location: `/usr/local/var/mysql/<filename>.local.err`
  - run `tail -f /usr/local/var/mysql/<filename>.local.err`
  - then re-run `mysql.servert start`
  - there will be an error related to `Invalid flags lib`
  - run `brew services stop mariadb@10.2`
  - (**BACKUP, BACKUP, BACKUP YOUR DBS! THIS WILL DELETE ALL DBs!**) 
     run `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql`
  - run

    ```
    mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami`
    --basedir="$(brew --prefix mariadb@10.2)"
    --datadir="/usr/local/var/mysql" --tempdir="/tmp"
    ```

    This will get the mariaDB Cellar installation path from brew
    and this will install the initial db.
  - instead of running `mysql_secure_installation` or
    `mariadb-secure-installation` **run**: `sudo mysql -u root`
  - this will drop to mysql shell
  - enter command: `use mysql;`
  - enter command: `ALTER USER 'root@localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';` (replace the )
  - enter command: `ALTER USER 'root@127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';` (replace the )
  - enter command: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
  - enter command: `exit`
  - now you can run `mysql -u root -p` and use the `<password>` entered in earlier step.

That's all!

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

1. Using `sudo` is the advised method. (e.g. `sudo mysql`)
2. Set the `root` account's password only when necessary.

### Introduction

Starting from [MariaDB 10.4.3](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-1043-release-notes/), the default authentication method changed to `unix_socket`.

> Once (the `unix_socket` plugin) has the (UNIX) user name, it will authenticate the connecting user as the MariaDB account that has the same user name. — [Authentication Plugin - Unix Socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/)

> Using unix_socket means that if you are the system root user, you can login as `root@locahost` without a password. — [Authentication from MariaDB 10.4](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-from-mariadb-104/#description)

To paraphrase, if you are the system's 'root' user, then you can access the MariaDB's 'root' user without any password. This can be achieved using the `sudo` command in linux and macOS.

### Unix

The `mysql` command is denied, because there is no MariaDB user whose name is 'username'.

```bash
username@hostname:~$ mysql --version
# mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.12-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

username@hostname:~$ mysql
# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

The `sudo mysql` command worked because there is a DB user named 'root' out-of-the-box.

```bash
username@hostname:~$ sudo mysql
# Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
# Your MariaDB connection id is 32
# Server version: 10.6.12-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Ubuntu 22.04

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT CURRENT_USER;
# +----------------+
# | CURRENT_USER   |
# +----------------+
# | root@localhost |
# +----------------+
# 1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

The 'root' and 'mysql' users have the authentication string set as `invalid`, which is not a valid password hash. This is the reason why the these accounts seem to have a password set.

```bash
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT user, plugin, authentication_string FROM mysql.user;
# +-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
# | User        | plugin                | authentication_string |
# +-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
# | mariadb.sys | mysql_native_password |                       |
# | root        | mysql_native_password | invalid               |
# | mysql       | mysql_native_password | invalid               |
# +-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
# 3 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

> Two all-powerful accounts are created by default — root and the OS user that owns the data directory, typically mysql. They are created as:

```sql
CREATE USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket OR mysql_native_password USING 'invalid'
CREATE USER mysql@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket OR mysql_native_password USING 'invalid'
```

— [Authentication from MariaDB 10.4](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-from-mariadb-104/#description)

### macOS and Brew

For some reason, the latest version of MariaDB installed with Brew has a different setup.

```bash
username@hostname ~ % mysql
# Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
# Your MariaDB connection id is 20
# Server version: 10.11.3-MariaDB Homebrew

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT CURRENT_USER;
# +--------------------+
# | CURRENT_USER       |
# +--------------------+
# | username@localhost |
# +--------------------+
# 1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT user, plugin, authentication_string FROM mysql.user;
# +-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
# | User        | plugin                | authentication_string |
# +-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
# | mariadb.sys | mysql_native_password |                       |
# | root        | mysql_native_password | invalid               |
# | username    | mysql_native_password | invalid               |
# | PUBLIC      |                       |                       |
# +-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
# 4 rows in set (0.003 sec)
```

The `mysql` command and the authentication WORKS without `sudo` because there is another MariaDB user created by default - it's username matches the macOS username.

### mysql_secure_installation

The infamous `mysql_secure_installation` script is probably not necessary in MariaDB 10.4+.

> Note that many of the reasons for the existence of this script no longer apply. In particular, from MariaDB 10.4, Unix socket authentication is applied by default, and there is usually no need to create a root password. See Authentication from MariaDB 10.4. — [mysql_secure_installation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_secure_installation/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this **`mysql_secure_installation`**  and it now works for me:

```
$ mysql_secure_installation
NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MariaDB
      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!

In order to log into MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user. If you've just installed MariaDB, and
haven't set the root password yet, you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none): << enter root here >>
```

I enter **`root`** as current password

```
OK, successfully used password, moving on...

Setting the root password or using the unix_socket ensures that nobody
can log into the MariaDB root user without the proper authorisation.
```

and do the rest