# MariaDB USB stick ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mariadb

My problem is that I need to run Maria db on a USB stick.

I have everything set up on my laptop on the USB stick and also get logged in via "mysql -u root", also already added a table. But when I made the USB stick to my PC and there again wanted to access the DB with "mysql -u root" I always get the error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
> password: NO)

Thats my bash script to start MariaDB

```
@echo off
%~d0
cd %~dp0mariadb
echo MySQL is starting

set DIR=%~dp0mariadb
set DATA=%DIR%\data
set PATH=%DIR%\bin;%PATH%

if not exist %DATA% ( 
    echo Creating the database 
    mysql_install_db 
    echo --------------------------- 
) 

start %~dp0mysql_cli.bat
bin\mysqld --standalone --console
rem pause
```

I have not set the password because it was only an attempt.
When I run "mysql -u root" on the laptop I can interact with the DB. But on other devices not.

I always have to change the path of the hard disk in the init file in Data. Which I have always done. I tried it again on the laptop and everything works there. I have also all root user output, where localhost is also present.  Expected was actually that I can log on normally with "mysql -u root" on the DB.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57805748/15186994

Comment: thx I solved it. I had to reset the password.